# chart-options not registering scaleStartValue

Tags: javascript, chart.js, angular-chart

this:

```
 <div class="chart chart-line" chart-options="{scaleStartValue:0,bezierCurve:false}"> </div>
```

Makes the expected result for the bezierCurve property, but doesn't change the starting value of Y axis. Is it bugged ? or do I need to specify another property here?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find in the [Chart.js Documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration), under Global chart configuration, that it requires `scaleOverride: false` to be set to true.

```
// Boolean - If we want to override with a hard coded scale
scaleOverride: false,

// ** Required if scaleOverride is true **
// Number - The number of steps in a hard coded scale
scaleSteps: null,
// Number - The value jump in the hard coded scale
scaleStepWidth: null,
// Number - The scale starting value
scaleStartValue: null,
```

With that in mind:

```html
<div class="chart chart-line" chart-options="{scaleOverride:true,scaleStartValue:0,bezierCurve:false}"> </div>
```